# MySQL View Optimization

Tags: mysql, view, query-optimization

I have a view (say '**v**') that is the combination of **10 tables** using several Joins and complex calculations. In that view, there are around 10 Thousand rows.

And then I select **1** row based on row as *WHERE id = 23456*.

Another possible way to use a larger query in which I can cut short the dataset to **1%** before the complex calculation starts.

> **Question**: Are SQL views optimized in some form?

Comment: views works best with the ALGORITHM=MERGE option read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html )

Comment: @RaymondNijland please elaborate.

Comment: I really wouldn’t bother with the view

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `Views` are just syntactic sugar.  There is not special optimization.  Think of views as being textually merged; *then* optimized.  That is, you could get the same optimizations (or not) by manually writing the equivalent `SELECT`.

If you would like to discuss the particular query further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE/VIEW` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  It may be that you are missing a useful 'composite' index.